# MirrorMaker2 does not mirror all messages from a compacted topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

**In some of the mirrored topics I'm missing data in the mirrored sink topic!**

The source Kafka cluster is configured by default with `log.rentention.ms=-1` and `log.cleanup.policy=compact`.

Pattern of usage: records are inserted and the with the key are also been nulled (so Kafka is used somehow like a database)

**MM2 Config:**

- sourceCluster config: (receive.buffer.bytes: 8192; max.poll.records: 10000)
- sinkCluster config: (batch.size:8192; offset.flush.timeout.ms:1200000; connection.max.idle.ms: 18000000)

following metrics are available for old and the new sink topic:

- Topic X: not nulled msg count: 63k new: 16k (I've also checked the head and tail there are the same creationTime)
- Topic Y: not nulled msg count: 30k new 18k; same story with the head/tail
- Topic Z: not nulled msg count: 136 new 136; SAME msg count

My is **assumption** is that when MM2 is consuming a batch and when it this batch same key is being nulled the first msg is not been mirrored. Is this correct ? If this is assumption is right how would one mirror an event-sourcing topic, If you want to recreated a state exactly in the same way how it is in the source topic?

Why messages are missing in the mirrored sink topic? How can I mirror all messages from the source topic?

Comment: Hi @imalik8088, have you solved this problem? I am trying to use mirrormaker2 and understanding how it works with compacted topics. I am also facing some problems because the topic replicated is not keeping the keys and assigning new different keys. Regards

Comment: Hola @LucidioVacas I added an answer to the question this might help. Are you sure that the mirrored topic has different keys? In my Setup (strimzi) I had no issues with the data, only less data in the mirrored topic (more in my article)

Comment: I'm running Strimzi MM2 to replicate data between 2 clusters, but none of the messages getting replicated, probably because keys are null and log.cleanup.policy=compact? I went thru your blog post but didn't find a solution. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve writing a blogpost about the issue and script help comparing the result of both topics https://imalik8088.de/posts/kafka_where_are_all_my_messages/